# Azure Logic Apps List by Trigger Time

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I would like to see the logic apps which did not have a run for example 1 month, are enabled and would like to disable them assuming they are no longer required to be active.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to find a script filter for all Azure functions which are enabled but not be triggered for a month? Which programming language you prefer? I'll provide you with a demo

Comment: I'm looking for a existing feature in the Azure Portal not by scripting using a specific programming language.

Comment: @JijoJoseph, is below answer(existing azure portal feature) helped you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below which is simpler and needs to be done manually within azure portal itself.

Go to respective Logic Apps and in the 'overview' blade itself, you can find both options:

1. 'Runs history + Trigger History + Metrics' and below that, you can
   use date filters as well. Let Confirm there are 'No Runs' or 'No
   Triggers' for the selected date filter.
2. Click 'Disable' option then. In Future if you need them to be
   active, Simply 'Enable' it again.

[image]

If you want all Logic Apps to be check at single shot, You can use Azure Monitor[+Kusto Query Language in Azure Log Analytics].

Answer (score 0):

You can find last 30 days trigger trace logs under Azure function **Monitor** blade:

[image]

So if there are no Invocation Traces logs means this function has not been requested while the last 30 days.